# IndexError: list index out of range, for re.match

Tags: python

below is part of a script I wrote, in which I have a problem in the if statement. 
If I want to use re.match('ATOM|MODEL',lines[i]), I got error message. removing the "|MODEL" in re.match, it will work. 
can anyone give me some hints why this happens? Thank you very much!

```
new_pdb=open(pdb_out,'w')
i=0
while (i<len(lines)):
    frag=lines[i].split()
# do not know why 'ATOM|MODEL' does not work
    if (re.match('ATOM',lines[i]) and "H" not in frag[2]):
        new_pdb.write(lines[i])
    i=i+1
new_pdb.close()
```

Below is the error message when I used re.match('ATOM|MODEL',lines[i]):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "non-h-1.py", line 17, in 
    if (re.match('ATOM|MODEL',lines[i]) and "H" not in frag[2]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the `lines` that starts with `MODEL` contains less than three whitespace-separated items, so `frag[2]` fails. If you remove `|MODEL` from the regex, `re.match()` fails and therefore Python doesn't even try to evaluate `frag[2]` which is why the error doesn't occur in that situation.

Other than that, you shouldn't be iterating over `lines` using a `while` loop - Python is not C. Use

```
for line in lines:
    frag = line.split()
    if (re.match('ATOM',line) and "H" not in frag[2]):
        new_pdb.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. Now I rewrote the if statement, trying to keep more lines. and it works:    'if (re.match('ATOM',lines[i]) and "H" not in frag[2]) or \
        re.match('MODEL|TER|ENDMDL',lines[i]):
        new_pdb.write(lines[i])'

Comment: sorry that I cannot format the code by ctrl+K in comments. It says 'code', but it seems not working.

Comment: @ziweiguan: Yes, multiline code in comments is not possible (and not useful). You can format small code snippets by surrounding them with backticks. Also, please look at the second part of my answer. Don't use counter variables unless you need their actual values for some other reason.

Comment: Thank you again, Tim. I replaced the while loop with for loop now. The output is the same. As you said, I'd better use for loop for this task.